# find, xargs なしでフォルダの下の全てのファイルの中身をcatしたい

Tags: android, linux, sh

abd shellにて、/proc/sys/net/ipv4 の下にあるファイル全てに対してcatを実行したいです。

ターゲットのフォルダに移動

```
adb shell
cd /proc/sys/net/ipv4
```

フォルダ内のファイル

```
ls
tcp_wmem
tcp_keepalive_intvl
tcp_congestion_control
.
.
.
```

１つのファイルだけcatする場合

```
cat tcp_congestion_control
$cubic
```

期待する結果

```
tcp_wmem                              
262200  524400  2560000
tcp_keepalive_intvl 
75
tcp_congestion_control
cubic
```

試したコードとエラー

```
$ find /proc/sys/net/ipv4/  -type f -exec cat {} \;
      /system/bin/sh: find: not found
```

Comment: `ls | xargs cat`
adb shellってxargs無いんでしたっけ？

Comment: はい、ないみたいなのです。
/proc/sys/net/ipv4 $ ls | xargs cat
/system/bin/sh: xargs: not found

Comment: root 化している端末なら、 [BusyBox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=stericson.busybox) を導入すると、 `find`, `xargs` その他のコマンドはそろいますよ。 (縛り付きの方が面白いけれども)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/proc/sys/net/ipv4` 直下のファイルだけでよければ簡単ですね。

```
$ for f in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/*; do [ -f "$f" ] || continue; echo "$f"; cat "$f"; done
```

再帰的にファイルを探したい、かつ `find` が利用できなければ、関数でも用意しましょう。例えば次のようになります。

```
$ ff() { for p in "$@"; do [ -d "$p" ] && { ff "$p"/*; continue; }; echo "$p"; done; }
```

この関数 `ff` (find file から名付けました)は、引数に指定したパスから再帰的にファイル (ディレクトリ以外) を探して表示します。

```
$ ff /proc/sys/net/ipv4
```

あとは適当にループして順次処理するだけです。

```
$ ff /proc/sys/net/ipv4 |while read f; do echo "$f"; cat "$f"; done
```

Answer (score -1):

下記のコマンドでどうでしょうか？

```
adb shell for file in `ls /proc/sys/net/ipv4/*`; do echo $file; cat $file; done
```

Comment: ls /proc/sys/net/ipv4/* ですと、サブディレクトリ内のファイルが相対パスになってしまいますので、その対応が必要かと思われます。